# Python tkinter : Add a vertical and horizontal scrollbar in the listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have this render_gui function in Python.

```
def render_gui():
    global root
    global prev_key
    global listbox, label1, entry1
    prev_key = 0

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Server Chat Application')

    scroll = Scrollbar(root)
    scroll.pack(side = "right" , fill= "y")
    listbox = Listbox(root, width=80, height=30)

    listbox.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=5,rowspan=3)    

    scroll.config(command = listbox.yview)

    label1 = ttk.Label(root, text='Message Entry Box : ')
    label1.grid(row=4,column=1)
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=60)
    entry1.grid(row=4, column=2)    

    root.geometry('490x520')
    #print('before main loop')
    root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
    #print('after main loop')
    root.mainloop()
```

It was throwing an error after I added the scrollbar thing. How will I encorporate a vertical and horizontal scrollbar in my listbox. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Below is the complete code. I have edited it and omit the pack thing replace it with grid function but the scrollbar wasn't showing. How am I gonna deal with this?

```
import os
import signal
import socket
import time
import threading
import keyboard
from threading import Thread


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def onKeyPress(event):
    global prev_key
    global root
    global listbox, label1, entry1


    if(event.keycode == 13):        
        print(Entry.get(entry1))
        msg = Entry.get(entry1)
        if len(str.encode(msg)) > 0:
            client.send(str.encode("\nserver > " + msg))
            listbox.insert(END, "server > " + msg)
            entry1.delete(0,END)

    if(event.keycode == 88) and (prev_key == 17):        
        root.destroy()
        try:            
            raise client.send(str.encode("***Server has been shutdowned***"))
        except:
            print ("You are not yet connected to any client to send shutdown notice.")
        sys.exit()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)

    prev_key = event.keycode

def render_gui():
    global root
    global prev_key
    global listbox, label1, entry1
    prev_key = 0

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Server Chat Application')

    scroll = Scrollbar(root)
    #scroll.pack(side = "right" , fill= "y")
    scroll.grid(row=0, column=10, rowspan=10, sticky='ns')
    listbox = Listbox(root, width=80, height=30)   



    listbox.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=5,rowspan=3)
    scroll.config(command = listbox.yview)
    listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)


    label1 = ttk.Label(root, text='Message Entry Box : ')
    label1.grid(row=4,column=1)
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=60)
    entry1.grid(row=4, column=2)    

    root.geometry('490x520')
    #print('before main loop')
    root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
    #print('after main loop')
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target= render_gui).start()
```

Comment: The listbox (or other scrollable widget) and the scrollbar each need to be told about the other; you only did half the job.  Typical code is `listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)` / `scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)`

Comment: What error? If you mean a NameError it means you need to use `tk.Scrollbar` instead of just `Scrollbar`.

Comment: It would be really helpful if your example was complete, so we could run it and see what's going on.

Comment: Or if you mean the _tkinter.TclError, that's because you used `pack()` for the Scrollbar when you should use `grid(row=0, column=10, rowspan=10, sticky='ns')`.

Comment: @Novel --> I have updated my post sir.

Comment: Please try to reduce this code to the smallest possible [mcve]. For example, if the problem is with a scrollbar working, you probably don't need the `onKeyPress` code in order to illustrate the problem. We also don't need a lot of the imports.